# An action of a group on a covering space

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

We see $S_3$ as the quotient of the free group on two elements and the normal subgroup $R$ generated by $\langle\sigma^3,\tau^2,\sigma\tau\sigma\tau\rangle$ where $\sigma$ and $\tau$ are the generators of the free group. The covering space corresponding to $R$ of the bouquet of 2 circle sould be the following:

[image: ...]

Now $S_3$ acts on this covering space, and the action should have two orbits. Could you explain me how is this action? (I mean, what are the images of the single edges?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us write $t=(12)$ and $s=(123)$, two elements of the symmetric group $S_3$ of degree $3$.

Construct a directed graph $\Gamma$ as follows:

- the vertices are the elements of $S_3$,
- if $g\in S_3$ is a vertex, there are two edges coming out of $g$ in $\Gamma$: one going from $g$ to $gt$ and the other going from $g$ to $gs$.

In other words, the set of edges is $$E=\{(g,gt)\in S_3\times S_3:g\in S_3\}\cup \{(g,gs)\in S_3\times S_3:g\in S_3\}.$$

We can draw a picture:

[image]

There is an action of $S_3$ on $\Gamma$ as follows: if $h\in S_3$, then

- the action of $h$ on the vertices of $\Gamma$ is by left multiplication by $h$: that is, a vertex $g\in S_3$ is mapped to $hg$;
- on the other hand, the action of $h$ on the edges is the induced one: if $(g_1,g_2)$ is one of the edges, then $h\cdot(g_1,g_2)=(hg_1,hg_2)$. It is easy to see that this latter element is, indeed, an edge of $\Gamma$.

It is very easy to see that the action of $S_3$ on the vertices of $\Gamma$ is simply transitive, so that the quotient graph $\Gamma/S_3$ has exactly one vertex, and that the action of $S_3$ on the edges of $\Gamma$ has exactly two orbits. It thus follows that $\Gamma/S_3$ is a two-leaved rose.

$$♦ ♦ ♦$$

Can you see how to go from this action of $S_3$ on $\Gamma$ to an action of $S_3$ on a CW-complex of dimension $1$, which is what you want?

Answer (score 0):

It might help to remember that $S_3$ is the same thing as $D_3$. So let's look for a "triangle-ish" shape for $D_3$ to act on. As you've drawn your picture, you can almost see it: the upper and lower three-cycles form a pair of triangles; in this way the whole graph is best visualized as a sort of triangular prism. Now $\sigma$ will act as a rotation, and $\tau$ will swap the upper and lower triangles. From this way of looking at things, it's perhaps easier to see that $S_3$ acts transitively on triangle edges (the non-vertical edges in your picture) and also acts transitively on the vertical edges. So these are your two orbits.